# How to directly sign up user in allauth django with google?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I use allauth django so that I can log into the site in one click. I don't really understand how:

1. save the user's email as a login
2. automatically register a user and log him in with a redirect to the desired page. Django takes me to social / signup, where I have to click the signup button, only then everything works. How do I register a user without this page?

Comment: First time, the user has to complete the signup process. This is required because they've to actually grant your app permission to use their account for logging in.

Comment: Why does it work at repl.it without any confirmation?

Comment: That's not true. For the very first time, user has to go through the whole process and grant permission. For subsequent logins, the user is automatically redirected to the desired page.

Comment: Try it on repl.it)
You have to choose your account with google window after that you will redirect to home page as authenticated